# Installing android studio latest build

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the latest android studio bundle stable version from android website. The problem is after installing and opening studio keeps getting following error.

1. Build-tools 21.1.1 not installed.
    I downloaded build-tools offline but do not know where to put that folder which has android-5.0
2. After keeping that in platforms (not sure) , I keep getting another error SDK tools revision 24.0.2 is not installed and support repository revision 11 not installed.

I do not have a internet connection on my pc ,so I cannot download directly to PC. Can you please give which files do I need to download for the successful installation of android studio. Please give offline download links if you have.

Thanks

Comment: No one to give an answer

Comment: Which channel are you on? Beta? or Stable?